# Trying to use a single field to create a starttime and endtime

Tags: sql-server-2019

I have the following data structure in a sql server database. I'm tying to for each detail record (headerid = 0) understand which header row it relates to, in the below table this fow example would be the starttime of id 1 and the starttime of id 4 for row 2 and 3.

| ID | StartDateTime | HeaderID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020-12-14T13:07:01.875 | 10000 |
| 2 | 2020-12-14T13:07:01.976 | 0 |
| 3 | 2020-12-14T13:07:02.496 | 0 |
| 4 | 2020-12-14T13:07:02.875 | 10001 |
| 5 | 2020-12-14T13:07:03.976 | 0 |
| 6 | 2020-12-14T13:07:04.896 | 0 |
| 7 | 2020-12-14T13:07:05.875 | 10003 |

I've tried to do this by joining the table to itself but can't seem to get it right and was looking for ideas of how i can achieve this?

Output would be either something like this, that shows a start & end time for each header (end time is the start time of the next header in chronological order)

| HeaderID | HeaderStartDateTime | HeaderEndDateTime |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020-12-14T13:07:01.875 | 2020-12-14T13:07:02.875 |
| 4 | 2020-12-14T13:07:02.875 | 2020-12-14T13:07:05.875 |
| 7 | 2020-12-14T13:07:05.875 | 2020-12-14T13:07:07.875 |

or with a header id for each of the detail rows (but this would be where the StartDateTime is between the HeaderStartDateTime and HeaderEndDateTime

| ID | StartDateTime | HeaderID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 2020-12-14T13:07:01.976 | 10000 |
| 3 | 2020-12-14T13:07:02.496 | 10000 |
| 5 | 2020-12-14T13:07:03.976 | 10001 |
| 6 | 2020-12-14T13:07:04.896 | 10001 |

Comment: How does the expected result looks like ?

Comment: I want to be able to show something like  ID, startTime, HeaderId but would only want to display for the detail rows i.e. 2,3,5,6 in the resultset

Comment: Have updated the question with a bit more details of the result that i'm looking for

Comment: where does `2020-12-14T13:07:07.875` come from? it isn't in the data provided

Comment: ah right, yeah, so for the that was a mock-up and would be the next header record or for the last in the series of detail rows would need to be the startdatetime of the last detail record.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `LEAD()` window function to get the `StartDateTime` for the next header

```
select ID, 
       StartDateTime, 
       EndDateTime = lead(StartDateTime) over (order by StartDateTime)
from   yourtable
where  HeaderID <> 0
```

As for the detail rows, use `CROSS APPLY()` and find the last header based on `StartDateTime`

```
select t.ID, t.StartDateTime, h.HeaderID
from   yourtable t
       cross apply
       (
           select top 1 h.HeaderID
           from   yourtable h
           where  h.HeaderID <> 0
           and    h.StartDateTime < t.StartDateTime
           order by h.StartDateTime desc
       ) h
where  t.HeaderID = 0
```

Comment: Thanks for you suggestion, this has helped me solve the issue thanks

Comment: Please do accept this as answer if it resolve your issue

Answer (score 0):

With the exception of the end date for id 7 (2020-12-14T13:07:07.875) which is not present in the sample data, the following approach meets you expected result:

```
CREATE TABLE yourtable (
    ID INT,
    StartDateTime DATETIME,
    HeaderID INT
);

INSERT INTO yourtable (ID, StartDateTime, HeaderID)
VALUES
    (1, '2020-12-14T13:07:01.875', 10000),
    (2, '2020-12-14T13:07:01.976', 0),
    (3, '2020-12-14T13:07:02.496', 0),
    (4, '2020-12-14T13:07:02.875', 10001),
    (5, '2020-12-14T13:07:03.976', 0),
    (6, '2020-12-14T13:07:04.896', 0),
    (7, '2020-12-14T13:07:05.875', 10003);
```

```
7 rows affected
```

```
SELECT
    HeaderID,
    StartDateTime AS HeaderStartDateTime,
    LEAD(StartDateTime) OVER (ORDER BY StartDateTime) AS HeaderEndDateTime
FROM yourtable
WHERE HeaderID <> 0
```

| HeaderID | HeaderStartDateTime | HeaderEndDateTime |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10000 | 2020-12-14 13:07:01.877 | 2020-12-14 13:07:02.877 |
| 10001 | 2020-12-14 13:07:02.877 | 2020-12-14 13:07:05.877 |
| 10003 | 2020-12-14 13:07:05.877 | *null* |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/2s1UIYfi)

It might be possible to fill in that NULL seen above by doing using current_timestamp - but this might be misleading as it depends on when it it is run.

```
SELECT
    HeaderID,
    StartDateTime AS HeaderStartDateTime,
    COALESCE(LEAD(StartDateTime) OVER (ORDER BY StartDateTime), CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) AS HeaderEndDateTime
FROM yourtable
WHERE HeaderID != 0;
```

Comment: Great thanks, have been able to get this working! Thanks for your suggestion